# Using variable from rostopic in another python file

Tags: python, ros

I am new at using ROS and I want to use an int that is received by a topic and use it in another python file. The listener.py receives the correct int but when i use it in another file it won't update and just print None. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

listener.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int32

class listenerPy:

    def __init__(self):
        self.received_integer = None

    def callback(self, data):      

        self.received_integer = data.data
        print(self.received_integer)     
        
    def listener(self):
        rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)        
        rospy.Subscriber('chatter', Int32, self.callback)
        rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listener = listenerPy()  # Instantiate the listenerPy class
        listener.listener()  # Call the listener method on the instance
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

other file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from listener import listenerPy
from time import sleep

def main():
    
    local_var = listenerPy() 
    while True:
        value = local_var.received_integer
        print(value)
        sleep(1)
            



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run both files standalone, you need some sort of shared memory. However, in your example, you need to actually start the listener in your *other* file.

```
def main():
    local_var = listenerPy()
    local_var.listener() 
    while True:
        value = local_var.received_integer
        print(value)
        sleep(1)
```

However, you call `rospy.spin()` in your ros node, which will block. So you should remove that call from your node.